Socket.IO listener intermittently fails to trigger event in Android app
I'm currently developing an Android app that utilizes Socket.IO to receive confirmation after a payment is successfully completed. The setup involves connecting to a Socket.IO server and listening for specific events. While the connection and event listening work reliably most of the time, there are instances where the listener fails to trigger the event, causing intermittent issues.
I've thoroughly reviewed my implementation and ensured that the connection to the Socket.IO server is established correctly. Additionally, I've tested various scenarios and configurations but haven't been able to pinpoint the exact cause of the intermittent listener failure.
I've also checked for any potential error messages or exceptions, but there doesn't seem to be any indication of why the listener occasionally fails to work.
I've spent significant time troubleshooting this issue but haven't found a solution yet. Any insights, suggestions, or similar experiences would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

SocketHelper

class SocketHelper(
    private val baseUrl : String,
    private val connectionToken : String
) {
    private lateinit var mSocket : Socket

    fun initSocket() {
        try {
            val options = IO.Options()
            options.forceNew = false
            options.transports = arrayOf(WebSocket.NAME)
            options.extraHeaders = mapOf("connection-token" to listOf(connectionToken))
            options.reconnection = true
            mSocket = IO.socket(baseUrl, options)
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            Timber.tag("Socket").e(ex)
        }
    }

    @Synchronized
    fun connectSocket(){
        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT) {
            Timber.tag("Socket").e("connected")
        }
        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT) {
            Timber.tag("Socket").e("Disconnected")
        }
        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR) { error ->
            Timber.tag("Socket").e("error: ${error[0]}")
        }
        mSocket.connect()
    }

    @Synchronized
    fun disconnectSocket() {
        mSocket.disconnect()
        mSocket.close()
        offEventListener()
    }

    private fun offEventListener(event: String ?= null){
        if(event != null)
            mSocket.off(event)
        else mSocket.off()
    }

    @Synchronized
    fun isSocketConnected() = mSocket.connected() ?: false

    @Synchronized
    fun onNewMessageReceived(event : String,emitter : Emitter.Listener){
        mSocket.on(event, emitter)
    }
}


MainActivity

 class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
        @Inject
        lateinit var socketHelper: SocketHelper

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.fragment_digital_payment)
            socketHelper.initSocket()
            socketHelper.onNewMessageReceived(identifier ?: "", onMessageReceived)
            socketHelper.connectSocket()
        }

        private val onMessageReceived = Emitter.Listener { args ->
            try {
                runOnUiThread {
                    showToastMessage("Payment successful")

                }
            } catch (exception: Exception) {
                Timber.e(exception.message)
            }
        }
    }

